# Help with Query to group rooms free between particular dates under their respective hotels

Tags: mysql

I am building an online hotel booking system.... Using php and mysql.... Users can search for and book hotels in a particular location .. The search criteria will be 
1. City or country 
 
2. Check - in and Check Out dates 
3. Number of guests 
My sql schema is as follows....

1. Table : hotels 
     hotel_id 
     hotel_name 
     country_id 
     city_id
2. Table : rooms 
    room_id 
    hotel_id 
    room_name 
    room_price 
    max_guests_allowed 
    no_total_rooms 
    no_booked_rooms
3. Table : reservations 
    reservation_id 
    room_id 
    
    hotel_id 
    check_in_date 
    check_out_date

Query to get rooms free between two given dates and can accommodate persons equal to or more than the no. of persons given by the user :

```
SELECT rooms.room_id, 
       rooms.room_name, 
       rooms.max_guests_allowed, 
       rooms.room_price, 
       hotels.hotel_id, 
       hotels.hotel_name 
FROM   hotel,rooms 
WHERE rooms.id NOT IN (SELECT room_id 
                       FROM   reservations 
                       WHERE  check_in_date < '$arrivalDate' 
                       AND    check_out_date > '$leaveDate') 
AND   rooms.max_guests_allowed >= '$no_of_guests';
```

Now... I have to display the result like....

```
1. Hotel 1 
     Room 1     No. of Rooms Free     Price   Max. Guests Allowed 
     Room 2     No. of Rooms Free     Price   Max. Guests Allowed 
     Room 3     No. of Rooms Free     Price   Max. Guests Allowed

2. Hotel 2
     Room 1     No. of Rooms Free     Price   Max. Guests Allowed 
     Room 2     No. of Rooms Free     Price   Max. Guests Allowed 
     Room 3     No. of Rooms Free     Price   Max. Guests Allowed

etc.. etc...
```

How should i modify my query to group the rooms under the hotels like i have mentioned above...????
Thanks a lot in advance....

Comment: Are your tables complete? Is the only relationship between hotel and room in the reservations table? Can I reserve the same room in a different hotel?

Comment: @Peter : You are right, Peter.... i've left out one field : hotel_id telling under which hotel the room is present.. i'll edit the post..... Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may be misunderstanding the question/query slightly, but couldn't you add:

```
ORDER BY hotels.hotel_name ASC,rooms.room_name ASC
```

to the end of the query to give you the results in hotel and then room order?

**Edit** to display in your original format, you could use some code similar to this.  I've done it in PHP here as you haven't specified what language you're using:

```
$currentHotel = -1;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array())
{
  if ($row["hotel_id"] != $currentHotel)
  {
    print "Hotel " . $row["hotel_id"] . "\n";
    $currentHotel = $row["hotel_id"];
  }

  // print your room details out here
  print "Room " . $row["room_name"];

  // ...
}
```

Comment: Yep.. But this will just order the hotels.. but will it group the rooms under their respective hotels..?

Comment: @SpikeTidE this will order by the first part (hotel_name) ascending, then by room_name ascending, but keeping the order of hotel_name.  So you should end up with what you've put in the question originally.  Can you try it and see?

Comment: @richsage : Hi... Sorry for the late reply... Was out for the weekend... Your suggestion worked... It arranged each room under it's hotel... but still not in the way i wanted... i.e the format i've sown above.. Instead it shows like...
Hotel 1 
  Room 1 
Hotel 1 
   Room 2    

Hotel 2
   Room 1
Hotel 2
   Room 2
etc... 
So.. trying to work with your idea to bring the format i wanted....

Comment: @SpikETide I've added some sample (PHP) code to display roughly how you want it - does this help?

Comment: @richsage : That's what i was expecting, rich!!!! I've been tearing my hair with complex functions... Can't believe this could've been so simple...  Thanks for helping me stop before i went completely bald..!! :) .... and yeah... i'm working with php...!!